# Create a custom hand shaped button from an image in css

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a custom button that looks and is shaped exactly as the hand in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD6vU.png) so I can add some functionality to it later. I have already tried using a svg path created with GIMP inside a button but it ends being a square button with a [hand image inside it's borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCcSF.png). Here is the path I've been using in case it helps:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="14.7222in" height="10.8889in"
 viewBox="0 0 1060 784"> <path id="Selection"
    fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 282.00,491.00
       C 288.28,483.27 299.19,460.23 304.21,450.28
         304.21,450.28 331.70,398.00 331.70,398.00
         335.20,391.35 343.33,373.62 348.10,369.22
         350.42,367.09 353.94,365.36 357.00,364.61
         368.51,361.78 382.89,373.58 377.17,390.00
         377.17,390.00 364.31,418.00 364.31,418.00
         364.31,418.00 360.69,427.00 360.69,427.00
         360.69,427.00 328.00,501.00 328.00,501.00
         337.42,491.55 344.52,480.85 352.70,470.42
         352.70,470.42 392.12,420.09 392.12,420.09
         392.12,420.09 400.13,410.00 400.13,410.00
         405.89,402.34 411.49,393.06 422.00,392.19
         434.87,391.12 448.35,405.76 437.73,423.00
         437.73,423.00 431.90,431.00 431.90,431.00
         431.90,431.00 418.91,450.00 418.91,450.00
         418.91,450.00 397.02,482.00 397.02,482.00
         397.02,482.00 364.00,530.00 364.00,530.00
         369.40,530.17 370.69,528.14 375.00,525.17
         375.00,525.17 392.00,513.14 392.00,513.14
         392.00,513.14 422.09,491.33 422.09,491.33
         422.09,491.33 444.00,476.02 444.00,476.02
         449.85,471.70 464.07,460.39 470.58,459.50
         485.59,457.42 497.02,474.17 488.30,486.96
         488.30,486.96 458.42,515.12 458.42,515.12
         458.42,515.12 411.00,558.92 411.00,558.92
         411.00,558.92 394.67,573.66 394.67,573.66
         394.67,573.66 370.73,602.00 370.73,602.00
         368.14,605.03 362.33,612.46 359.00,613.89
         355.81,615.26 349.42,612.95 346.00,612.13
         339.93,610.68 327.19,609.08 321.00,609.00
         298.14,608.74 275.84,613.64 256.00,625.31
         252.69,627.26 245.78,631.85 243.01,634.30
         241.70,635.45 239.04,637.82 239.04,639.71
         239.04,644.22 248.15,636.36 249.00,635.74
         261.34,626.84 272.41,622.01 287.00,618.01
         292.86,616.40 311.02,614.08 317.00,614.08
         317.00,614.08 339.00,616.15 339.00,616.15
         339.00,616.15 357.00,619.71 357.00,619.71
         357.00,619.71 371.00,617.15 371.00,617.15
         371.00,617.15 418.00,612.83 418.00,612.83
         418.00,612.83 442.00,610.46 442.00,610.46
         455.78,610.96 466.04,624.86 461.05,638.00
         456.71,649.42 446.39,651.47 436.00,655.42
         436.00,655.42 379.00,678.32 379.00,678.32
         355.75,687.16 335.59,696.45 311.00,702.11
         311.00,702.11 277.00,708.80 277.00,708.80
         273.22,709.53 263.93,710.85 261.00,712.31
         255.15,715.23 246.06,728.07 241.32,733.58
         241.32,733.58 213.24,765.83 213.24,765.83
         208.94,770.91 201.59,778.41 199.00,784.00
         199.00,784.00 46.00,784.00 46.00,784.00
         46.00,784.00 14.00,784.00 14.00,784.00
         9.23,783.91 2.63,781.40 0.57,776.68
         -0.14,775.05 0.00,771.83 0.00,770.00
         0.00,770.00 0.00,753.00 0.00,753.00
         0.13,745.37 5.41,743.34 11.00,738.58
         11.00,738.58 40.83,712.51 40.83,712.51
         40.83,712.51 123.00,641.27 123.00,641.27
         123.00,641.27 148.73,619.05 148.73,619.05
         153.36,615.05 161.09,608.78 164.46,604.00
         167.50,599.67 170.56,590.24 172.86,585.00
         178.00,573.29 182.87,563.96 189.45,553.00
         198.92,537.21 209.85,522.70 220.87,508.00
         220.87,508.00 237.24,485.00 237.24,485.00
         238.94,481.34 239.88,475.14 241.01,471.00
         241.01,471.00 251.13,428.00 251.13,428.00
         251.13,428.00 258.35,398.00 258.35,398.00
         259.28,393.92 261.31,384.30 263.23,381.04
         266.42,375.59 272.92,373.28 279.00,374.21
         294.03,376.50 290.69,392.46 289.98,403.00
         289.98,403.00 283.91,466.00 283.91,466.00
         283.30,474.36 281.25,482.56 282.00,491.00 Z
       M 265.16,485.99
       C 261.01,488.32 264.21,490.50 267.02,492.27
         267.02,492.27 287.00,503.58 287.00,503.58
         287.00,503.58 355.00,541.30 355.00,541.30
         355.00,541.30 372.00,550.76 372.00,550.76
         373.71,551.66 376.74,553.48 378.70,552.99
         383.00,551.92 378.61,547.83 376.94,546.78
         376.94,546.78 355.00,534.42 355.00,534.42
         355.00,534.42 294.00,500.58 294.00,500.58
         288.30,497.32 270.41,486.46 265.16,485.99 Z
       M 288.00,502.00
       C 288.00,502.00 289.00,502.00 289.00,502.00
         289.00,502.00 288.00,503.00 288.00,503.00
         288.00,503.00 288.00,502.00 288.00,502.00 Z
       M 325.00,520.00
       C 330.21,523.38 338.85,526.00 342.00,531.00
         346.71,531.16 348.02,532.50 351.00,536.00
         344.47,533.98 328.31,525.75 325.00,520.00 Z
       M 365.00,531.00
       C 365.00,531.00 364.00,531.00 364.00,531.00
         364.00,531.00 365.00,532.00 365.00,532.00
         365.00,532.00 365.00,531.00 365.00,531.00 Z
       M 352.00,535.00
       C 352.00,535.00 360.00,541.00 360.00,541.00
         355.99,539.75 353.55,539.11 352.00,535.00 Z
       M 361.00,540.00
       C 366.34,543.38 375.83,545.75 378.00,552.00
         372.51,549.10 363.96,545.56 361.00,540.00 Z
       M 291.00,614.00
       C 304.90,609.75 326.68,610.67 341.00,613.08
         346.21,613.96 354.91,614.42 358.00,619.00
         340.21,613.18 329.33,612.84 311.00,612.85
         305.70,612.85 294.59,615.02 291.00,614.00 Z
       M 263.00,625.00
       C 266.68,619.28 283.22,614.96 290.00,614.00
         290.00,614.00 272.00,621.28 272.00,621.28
         272.00,621.28 253.00,631.36 253.00,631.36
         253.00,631.36 239.00,641.00 239.00,641.00
         242.18,634.82 255.94,625.01 263.00,625.00 Z
       M 247.00,634.00
       C 247.00,634.00 246.00,634.00 246.00,634.00
         246.00,634.00 247.00,635.00 247.00,635.00
         247.00,635.00 247.00,634.00 247.00,634.00 Z
       M 241.00,639.00
       C 241.00,639.00 240.00,639.00 240.00,639.00
         240.00,639.00 241.00,640.00 241.00,640.00
         241.00,640.00 241.00,639.00 241.00,639.00 Z" />
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="14.7222in" height="10.8889in"
 viewBox="0 0 1060 784"> 
  

  <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="translate(0.000000,778.000000) scale(0.101500,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
    <path d="M2580 2905 c0 -20 -3 -18 612 -359 504 -280 580 -316 566 -273 -4 10 -168 105 -488 281 -52 29 -222 123 -377 209 -154 86 -288 157 -297 157 -9 0 -16 -7 -16 -15z"/>
    <path d="M2887 1664 c-102 -18 -207 -54 -311 -105 -106 -52 -246 -155 -246 -181 0 -29 26 -21 84 26 267 217 673 290 1058 191 43 -12 64 -13 71 -6 26 26 -55 55 -223 81 -92 14 -341 11 -433 -6z"/>
  </g>
  <path id="Selection"
    fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
    d="M 282.00,491.00
       C 288.28,483.27 299.19,460.23 304.21,450.28
         304.21,450.28 331.70,398.00 331.70,398.00
         335.20,391.35 343.33,373.62 348.10,369.22
         350.42,367.09 353.94,365.36 357.00,364.61
         368.51,361.78 382.89,373.58 377.17,390.00
         377.17,390.00 364.31,418.00 364.31,418.00
         364.31,418.00 360.69,427.00 360.69,427.00
         360.69,427.00 328.00,501.00 328.00,501.00
         337.42,491.55 344.52,480.85 352.70,470.42
         352.70,470.42 392.12,420.09 392.12,420.09
         392.12,420.09 400.13,410.00 400.13,410.00
         405.89,402.34 411.49,393.06 422.00,392.19
         434.87,391.12 448.35,405.76 437.73,423.00
         437.73,423.00 431.90,431.00 431.90,431.00
         431.90,431.00 418.91,450.00 418.91,450.00
         418.91,450.00 397.02,482.00 397.02,482.00
         397.02,482.00 364.00,530.00 364.00,530.00
         369.40,530.17 370.69,528.14 375.00,525.17
         375.00,525.17 392.00,513.14 392.00,513.14
         392.00,513.14 422.09,491.33 422.09,491.33
         422.09,491.33 444.00,476.02 444.00,476.02
         449.85,471.70 464.07,460.39 470.58,459.50
         485.59,457.42 497.02,474.17 488.30,486.96
         488.30,486.96 458.42,515.12 458.42,515.12
         458.42,515.12 411.00,558.92 411.00,558.92
         411.00,558.92 394.67,573.66 394.67,573.66
         394.67,573.66 370.73,602.00 370.73,602.00
         368.14,605.03 362.33,612.46 359.00,613.89
         355.81,615.26 349.42,612.95 346.00,612.13
         339.93,610.68 327.19,609.08 321.00,609.00
         298.14,608.74 275.84,613.64 256.00,625.31
         252.69,627.26 245.78,631.85 243.01,634.30
         241.70,635.45 239.04,637.82 239.04,639.71
         239.04,644.22 248.15,636.36 249.00,635.74
         261.34,626.84 272.41,622.01 287.00,618.01
         292.86,616.40 311.02,614.08 317.00,614.08
         317.00,614.08 339.00,616.15 339.00,616.15
         339.00,616.15 357.00,619.71 357.00,619.71
         357.00,619.71 371.00,617.15 371.00,617.15
         371.00,617.15 418.00,612.83 418.00,612.83
         418.00,612.83 442.00,610.46 442.00,610.46
         455.78,610.96 466.04,624.86 461.05,638.00
         456.71,649.42 446.39,651.47 436.00,655.42
         436.00,655.42 379.00,678.32 379.00,678.32
         355.75,687.16 335.59,696.45 311.00,702.11
         311.00,702.11 277.00,708.80 277.00,708.80
         273.22,709.53 263.93,710.85 261.00,712.31
         255.15,715.23 246.06,728.07 241.32,733.58
         241.32,733.58 213.24,765.83 213.24,765.83
         208.94,770.91 201.59,778.41 199.00,784.00
         199.00,784.00 46.00,784.00 46.00,784.00
         46.00,784.00 14.00,784.00 14.00,784.00
         9.23,783.91 2.63,781.40 0.57,776.68
         -0.14,775.05 0.00,771.83 0.00,770.00
         0.00,770.00 0.00,753.00 0.00,753.00
         0.13,745.37 5.41,743.34 11.00,738.58
         11.00,738.58 40.83,712.51 40.83,712.51
         40.83,712.51 123.00,641.27 123.00,641.27
         123.00,641.27 148.73,619.05 148.73,619.05
         153.36,615.05 161.09,608.78 164.46,604.00
         167.50,599.67 170.56,590.24 172.86,585.00
         178.00,573.29 182.87,563.96 189.45,553.00
         198.92,537.21 209.85,522.70 220.87,508.00
         220.87,508.00 237.24,485.00 237.24,485.00
         238.94,481.34 239.88,475.14 241.01,471.00
         241.01,471.00 251.13,428.00 251.13,428.00
         251.13,428.00 258.35,398.00 258.35,398.00
         259.28,393.92 261.31,384.30 263.23,381.04
         266.42,375.59 272.92,373.28 279.00,374.21
         294.03,376.50 290.69,392.46 289.98,403.00
         289.98,403.00 283.91,466.00 283.91,466.00
         283.30,474.36 281.25,482.56 282.00,491.00 Z
       M 265.16,485.99
       C 261.01,488.32 264.21,490.50 267.02,492.27
         267.02,492.27 287.00,503.58 287.00,503.58
         287.00,503.58 355.00,541.30 355.00,541.30
         355.00,541.30 372.00,550.76 372.00,550.76
         373.71,551.66 376.74,553.48 378.70,552.99
         383.00,551.92 378.61,547.83 376.94,546.78
         376.94,546.78 355.00,534.42 355.00,534.42
         355.00,534.42 294.00,500.58 294.00,500.58
         288.30,497.32 270.41,486.46 265.16,485.99 Z
       M 288.00,502.00
       C 288.00,502.00 289.00,502.00 289.00,502.00
         289.00,502.00 288.00,503.00 288.00,503.00
         288.00,503.00 288.00,502.00 288.00,502.00 Z
       M 325.00,520.00
       C 330.21,523.38 338.85,526.00 342.00,531.00
         346.71,531.16 348.02,532.50 351.00,536.00
         344.47,533.98 328.31,525.75 325.00,520.00 Z
       M 365.00,531.00
       C 365.00,531.00 364.00,531.00 364.00,531.00
         364.00,531.00 365.00,532.00 365.00,532.00
         365.00,532.00 365.00,531.00 365.00,531.00 Z
       M 352.00,535.00
       C 352.00,535.00 360.00,541.00 360.00,541.00
         355.99,539.75 353.55,539.11 352.00,535.00 Z
       M 361.00,540.00
       C 366.34,543.38 375.83,545.75 378.00,552.00
         372.51,549.10 363.96,545.56 361.00,540.00 Z
       M 291.00,614.00
       C 304.90,609.75 326.68,610.67 341.00,613.08
         346.21,613.96 354.91,614.42 358.00,619.00
         340.21,613.18 329.33,612.84 311.00,612.85
         305.70,612.85 294.59,615.02 291.00,614.00 Z
       M 263.00,625.00
       C 266.68,619.28 283.22,614.96 290.00,614.00
         290.00,614.00 272.00,621.28 272.00,621.28
         272.00,621.28 253.00,631.36 253.00,631.36
         253.00,631.36 239.00,641.00 239.00,641.00
         242.18,634.82 255.94,625.01 263.00,625.00 Z
       M 247.00,634.00
       C 247.00,634.00 246.00,634.00 246.00,634.00
         246.00,634.00 247.00,635.00 247.00,635.00
         247.00,635.00 247.00,634.00 247.00,634.00 Z
       M 241.00,639.00
       C 241.00,639.00 240.00,639.00 240.00,639.00
         240.00,639.00 241.00,640.00 241.00,640.00
         241.00,640.00 241.00,639.00 241.00,639.00 Z" />
```

Comment: Hello Rizeen. That solves the problem with the lines inside the hand, but the actual image element is still shaped like a rectangle. I'm trying to make the sgv or the button to be shaped exactly as the hand in a way that it only responds to the cursor when it is exactly over the image. Still I don't know if that is possible with css.